# how to access the command line for xampp on windows

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I am running Xampp on my Windows 7 machine and was wondering if and how I could run commands for xampp via a command line. commands like php phpfile.php

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

- You can set ***environment variables*** as mentioned in the other answers (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408671/842768))

  or
- you can open ***Start > CMD*** as administrator and write

  `C:\xampp\php phpfile.php`

Comment: For me it worked only when I typed in cmd `C:\xampp\php\php phpfile.php`

Comment: Modern XAMPP has a Shell that you can start from the XAMPP control centre - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62500117/334497 (below on this page)

Answer (score 79):

XAMPP does not have a pre build console to run `php` or `mysql` commands, so, you have to add to windows `PATH` **environment variables**, these 2: `;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\xampp\php;`

Then you should be able to execute `php` and `mysql` commands from the CMD.

### UPDATE

I tested it, and it works.

Comment: For Windwos 10: `Control Panel\System and Security\System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables`

Comment: Modern XAMPP has a Shell that you can start from the XAMPP control centre - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62500117/334497 (below on this page)

Answer (score 31):

Thank you guys for this answers. But I think the accepted answer needs more clarity, As i found difficulty in getting the solution.

1. We may set the **environment variable** as mentioned in the answer by w0rldart .

   In this case(after seting **envmnt var**) we may run the phpFile by opening **start >> CMD** and typing commands like,

   `php.exe <path to file location>`

   or

   `php <path to file location>`

   **example:**

   ```
   php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php
   ```
2. you can open **Start >> CMD** as administrator and write like

   `<path to php.exe in xampp's php folder> <path to file location>`

   **example:**

   ```
   C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php
   ```

   or

   ```
   C:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php
   ```

Hopes this will help somebody.

Comment: hey greate example

Answer (score 11):

Run PHP file from command Promp.

Please set **Environment Variable** as per below mention steps.

1. Right Click on **MY Computer** Icon and Click on Properties or Go to **"Control Panel\System and Security\System".**
2. Select **"Advanced System Settings"** and select **"Advance"** Tab
3. Now Select **"Environment Variable"** option and select **"Path"** from **"System Variables"** and click on "Edit" button
4. Now set path where **php.exe** file is available - For example if **XAMPP** install in to C: drive then Path is **"C:\xampp\php"**
5. After set path Click Ok and Apply.

Now open Command prompt where your source file are available and run command "php test.php"

Answer (score 9):

In case some one wants to know how to set up **Environment variables**

1. Click on the windows button on the bottom left and go to System
2. Click the Advanced System Settings link in the left column
3. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables button near the bottom of that tab.
4. In the Environment Variables window , highlight the Path variable in the "System variables" section and click the Edit button. Add the path lines with the paths you want the computer to access.

Once you have done that you can run using the command from the start->command line as below

```
php <path to file location>
```

Answer (score 9):

Like all other had said above, you need to add path. But not sure for what reason if I add `C:\xampp\php` in path of *System Variable* **won't work** but if I add it in path of *User Variable* work fine.

*Although I had added and using other command line tools by adding in system variables work fine*

So just in case if someone had same problem as me. Windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the version 3.2.4 of the XAMPP Control Panel, there is button that can open a command line prompt (red rectangle in the next figure)

[image]

After pressing the button, you will see the command prompt window.

[image]

From this window you can navigate through the different folders and start the different services available.

Answer (score 4):

Please renember: 
When you change the path variable, you need to restart the console otherwise the path variable is not updated and does not seem to work.

Comment: your answer is also important step in above process, thanks dude, u deserve +1.

Answer (score 1):

Xampp has the php application under: C:\xampp\php file directory ... if you input C:\xampp\php\php in CMD it should enter the php application.

Answer (score 1):

A faster option would be to use CMD as administrator. You could type, for example:

`setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\xampp\php"`

After this, you need to close CMD and reopen. For test type:

`php -v`

Answer (score 1):

in case you want to directly type e.g. `mysql -u root...` in your terminal, **all of these answers are ugly :)**

### one line answer:

1. find `xampp_shell.bat` file (it's in the root of xampp folder)
2. open it in an editor
3. replace all of "zero variables"(%~dp0) with the absolute location of xampp folder(for me, i replaced all "%~dp0" with `C:\xampp\`)
4. save the file, rename it to `xampp.bat`, move it to `%SystemRoot%\System32` (probably it's `C:\Windows\System32`

now in **cmd** just type `xampp`,all of your environment variables are set & you're ready to go...

**note:** to exit from xampp mode type `EXIT;`

---

**approach 2: add'em directly to your environment variables:**
[you can read about it here](https://dinocajic.medium.com/add-xampp-php-to-environment-variables-in-windows-10-af20a765b0ce)

Answer (score 0):

For windows 11 we have to add both path here, like

C:\xampp81\php
C:\xampp\php

and restart / after that run C:\xampp81 xampp-controll.exe

and check php -v in cmd

[image]