# PHP Apache Increase Maximum Number of Concurrent Connections per Client

Tags: php, apache, powershell, concurrency, xampp

I would like to run dozens of long-running PHP scripts simultaneously, using XAMPP. Each script runs for more than 2 hours and does not use sessions, cookies, etc.

For my first test run, I tried opening up 10 of these scripts on my browser, but only the first six that I opened actually began execution (I know this because at the beginning of each script, I immediately open up a file to write status updates there--nothing gets written from any of the scripts except the first 6).

Is there a code I can put at the top of each script, or some PHP settings I can change, or any other ways I can make it so that I can simultaneously run as many PHP scripts as I want to?

---

**EDIT Here is how to accomplish this:**

1) Download PowerShell 2 (or the compatible version with your Windows version) from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929

2) Install it and restart your computer.

3) Make a new file "example.ps1" and save it to a directory of your choice (e.g. c:\examples\example.ps1). Put this code in that file:

```
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\1.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\2.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\3.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\4.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\5.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\6.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\7.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\8.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\9.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\10.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\11.php}
```

4) Click on "Start" -> "Run" and type in "powershell" (without quotes).

5) After PowerShell initiates, type in the following and press enter:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Then press "y" to set the changes.

6) Now type in (make sure to enter in the full file path):

```
c:\examples\example.ps1
```

7) To see your jobs simply type in:

```
get-job
```

To stop a job use this command:

```
stop-job JobName
```

Comment: better fit over at server fault

Comment: why does this have to run inside apache?

Comment: @Jack, I'm running this locally off my computer (Windows XP). Is there a different way I can run it besides inside Apache?\n@bretterer, thanks, I didn't know about http://serverfault.com/

Comment: cron jobs or scheduled jobs, but definitely best run from the CLI (and yes, you can run CLI tasks with your xampp installation)

Comment: Yes you can use the command line php; btw, to reply to anyone use @ followed by their handle, thanks

Comment: @Jack, do you have any examples of how I can run multiple scripts using command line? I found this to run one script, but what about several? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10774204/1303123

Comment: @Pamela first thing that comes to mind: write a .bat file, create a shortcut on your desktop and click click click ;)

Comment: @Jack I tried executing this batch file:

[code]    start php 1.php
    start php 2.php
    start php 3.php
[/code]
It only opened a command prompt window; I closed that window, then two more command prompt windows opened up executing 2.php and 3.php.

I want to run as many scripts as I want all simultaneously and all in the background. What is the best way to accomplish this, and how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers will block simultaneous connections. Use command line and you also will have less issues with timeouts. Plus output is instant so you can echo all the time.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that it was my browser (Firefox) that was blocking the simultaneous connections, nor did I realize this could be the cause of timeouts, and that helpful information about live echoing. Do you have any examples of how I can run multiple scripts using the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to run the scripts via a browser? Isn't it easier to run such long-running script straight from the terminal with php-cli? That way, you can start up as many processes as you want.