# Yii new project cmd

Tags: php, yii, xampp, command-prompt, system-variable

I have been using xampp server. I'm trying to make a new project. 
I have been giving a command,

> C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\yiic

It says,

`php.exe` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have also set the system variable, path as

> C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\yiic

. Whats the problem here?

Comment: I added the php path. Now it works.@Naupal Thanks for the answer. Link wasn't needed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the path to `php` also

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753133/932319)

Answer (score 1):

You need add PHP path to system environment or use the direct path of php.exe,just like:

```
    c:\xampp\php\php.exe yiic webapp c:\xampp\htdocs\yourappname
```

Answer (score 0):

This what worked with me:

```
D:\ProgramFiles\xampp\php\php D:\ProgramFiles\xampp\htdocs\yii\f
ramework/yiic webapp D:\ProgramFiles\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName
```