# php is not recognized on cmd

Tags: php, cmd, path, xampp

when I run this command on CMD widow I get this error I edited the environment variables 
to TEMP

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\xampp\php
```

and TMP TO

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\xampp\php
```

but I still get the same error

```
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753024/how-to-access-the-command-line-for-xampp-on-windows. It is probable because you forgot to add the last semi-colon. Also, whenever you update an environment variable you should restart your machine as well for changes to take place.

Comment: I get that when I run this commend on your link mr @AntonioHernández
C:\xampp\php phpfile.php

The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: The second comment below the accepted answer is what you need

Comment: @AntonioHernández I used the answer for this user skt and that's worked thank you