# I get an error whenever i try to use mysqldump in PHP. How can I properly import it and use it?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't use mysqldump without getting an error.

I'm writing a script in php that is supposed to make a backup of my data, however I can't get mysqldump to work as a command.

I'm only having trouble with the mysqldump command in the exec() method of PHP.

```
exec("mysqldump --user=exampleUser --host=exampleHost exampleDB > filepath/file.sql");
```

The expected result is that a new file called `file.sql` gets created under the given filepath (creating the file works) and that in this file all information is saved.
The actual result is an empty file.sql under the given path.
The Error message is:

> The command "mysqldump" is either misspelled or could not be found.

Comment: Use the **full path**, e.g. `/usr/something/something/.../mysqldump`.

Comment: I did, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Lovahrk did work

Comment: @kellymandem not yet.

Comment: a) what OS are you doing this on? b) for piece of mind, could you edit question with exec() command using full path to `mysqldump` as deceze suggested with error given back underneath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
<?php

    /* For a unix like system, use this */
    exec('$(which mysqldump) -u admin -p test', $output);

    /* For windows use this, after adding to `mysql bin` folder to your PATH */
    exec('mysqldump -u admin -p test', $output);

    $content = implode("\n", $output);
    $path = '';
    $file = $path . 'test.sql';
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

**Note**: You need to add `mysql bin` folder to your path for windows, if that is what you are using and you can follow instructions in [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html) link how to do it if used the official standalone mysql installation and if you used xampp you can go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753024/how-to-access-the-command-line-for-xampp-on-windows) on how to do it

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but that sadly didn't work either.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Using windows 10

Comment: @Lovahrk i have updated my answer to provide with options on how you could possibly solve the issue on windows