# fileinfo.dll missing despite being un-commented in php.ini

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php, laravelcollective

I'm learning laravel and trying to install laravel collective. Using Xampp, PHP 7.3.4, Laravel 5.8.14.

I get the following issue in GitBash when trying to do so:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
- league/flysystem 1.0.51 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
- league/flysystem 1.0.51 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
- league/flysystem 1.0.51 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
- Installation request for league/flysystem (locked at 1.0.51) -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.51].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.1\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

in my php.ini file the `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` line is not commented, I'm editing the `xampp/htdocs/php/php.ini` file which is right according to `phpinfo()` but the above would seem to indicate the `php.ini` file on my machine.

```
php --ini produces the following:


Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.1\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Not sure where to go from here?

Comment: Look at this line `Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Program Files (x86)\iisexpress\PHP\v7.1\php.ini`

Comment: Remove the old php PHP from the windows PATH

Comment: Then you may have to add the XAMPP PHP folder to the path

Comment: I can't edit those on my work machine. I'm confused as to why it'd be looking there and how i can point it to the xampp folder instead?

Comment: You mean you cannot edit the Windows PATH environment variable? If thats the case then you have better get your support people involved

Comment: I have C:\xampp\php in the Edit environment variable pane.

Comment: Ok, but did you remove the `C:\Program Files (x86)\iisexpress\PHP` as well

Comment: It isn't there, I have C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin; C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\ComposerSetup; C:\xampp\php; %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps. It's entirely possible I'm looking in the wrong place though.

Comment: Did you look at **User** and **System** variables?

Comment: have you restarted the server and the gitbash ?

Comment: @AhmedAboud Server does not need restarting when yo are using the PHP CLI and changing the PATH

Comment: i don't know but xampp acts funky when i un comment the php.ini and not restart the apache and the cmd

Comment: @AhmedAboud The issue is that the CLI is reading the wrong `php.ini` file, because the Windows PATH is pointing to a different (not XAMPP) PHP

Comment: @AhmedAboud I have restarted both yes.

Comment: When you say User and System variables do you mean the two sections within the Environment Variables pane? If not, I'm lost, not been in here before and just trying to educate myself about it on google now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753024/how-to-access-the-command-line-for-xampp-on-windows/46408671#46408671 maybe related ?

Comment: Ahh I mis-read the Path value in System variables, that is going to C:\Program Files (x86)\iss express\PHP\v7.1, can't edit that, guess I need to speak to the admins. Thanks for all your help!