# Laravel local server setup in windows

Tags: laravel, offline

I am new here and I tried to start a project offline. From the beginning I have the same problem. I have a local domain (syworkx.local). I have line in hosts (in windows directory), I have line in httpd-vhosts.conf with info where is exactly the servis. I have also info in .env what is the app_dir.

The homepage is works ok but after successfully login I have a wrong route. I see the syworkx.local/dashboard but from wrong directory.

I have the same if I put localhost or syworkx.local in chrome. I have many projects in my xampp.

What exactly I have to change to start the project? I would like to explain that online everything is works good.

Please somebody help me. I know it is a small detail but my project doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you add xampp PHP path to environment variable?

Comment: Check how to add PHP path to environment variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753024/how-to-access-the-command-line-for-xampp-on-windows/46408671#46408671

Comment: Could you explain it to me? What exactly I have to do?

Comment: If you are building small project or learning laravel you can use PHP command to serve laravel project. For your php command to work on cmd or powershell you need to add PHP path to environment variable.

Comment: Run command `php -v` to check if environment variable is properly set. If set correctly you'll see PHP version on cmd

Comment: Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Tomek> php -v
PHP 7.3.7 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2019 14:34:10) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.7, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
PS C:\Users\Tomek>

Comment: Awesome. Writing my answer. Wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command on laravel project folder

```
php -S localhost:3000 -t public
```

- Assuming you didn't change laravel default code.
- You can put any port instead of 3000. But if you put port 80/8000 you might see error.
- Once the command successfully ran then check browser with localhost:3000

This should work

Comment: Now, it works but I have to delete 's' from https. When I deleted 's' from https:localhost:3000 and I have only http:localhost:3000 my project WORK. Where can I change it in the laravel project?

Comment: You can set `'url' => 'http://youDomain.com'` in `config/app.php` or you could use a middleware class Laravel 5 - redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: Could it be also like this? APP_URL=localhost:3000 You said me I have to open from your suggest.

Comment: Probably, yes. Try and let me know.

Comment: No, I have to delete 's'. All the time it want ssl.

Comment: Are you still using xampp?

Comment: Yes, I have to turn off xampp?

Comment: Can you change the domain name extension from local to dev? Change that, test and update me

Comment: Not on the browser URL input but from etc and Apache conf. Should be like syworkx.dev

Comment: etc? What is is?

Comment: I mean host file in windows

Comment: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: in .env:
APP_URL=syworkx.dev

host:
127.0.0.1 syworkx.dev

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@kfzpix.de
    ServerName syworkx.dev
    DocumentRoot "D:/Documents/Martin/projects/syworkx/public/"
        <Directory "D:/Documents/Martin/projects/syworkx/public/">
                    DirectoryIndex index.php
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: What about host file?

Comment: do you want acess via team viewer?

Comment: `https://gist.github.com/zenorocha/18b10a14b2deb214dc4ce43a2d2e2992` change 127.0.0.1 localhost to syworkx.dev

Comment: Save, restart Apache server, try on browser

Comment: The samem NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: It works only with your localhost:3000 but I have to delete 's'

Comment: Its not must that you need SSL on local server for testing. Why don't you work without SSL?

Comment: I have a SSL from nginx.

Comment: Work without SSL for now. On server you can use SSL, there's a free SSL certificate provider called let's encrypt

Comment: Ok, but what now? How could iz be fix?

Comment: I know that when I move mouse over the link and I see the link with https:xxxxxx Somewhere in app it must be change.

Comment: This is strange and need fixing. I'll check internet and update you. You check too, let me know what you find

Comment: If I change <a href="{{ route('users.index') }}">List</a> for <a href="users">List</a> project works.

Comment: I thing yes with this solution yes.

Comment: How can I give you a feedback?

Comment: On my answer click on up sign or in comment press small up icon

Comment: But it works not very good. I have no search function, no users function. It is no good solution. I have also many, many orders from database and I can't see it. I have to cancel 's' (from https) but I have arounf 100.000 orders in database. We have to find another solution. It must be from laravel route. It is the problem. The route. I thing.

Comment: It must be like that: <a href="{{ route('users.index') }}">List</a>  It must works with route. Without route project has only 25% of possibility.