# Add XAMPP shell to new 'Windows Terminal'

Tags: json, windows, terminal, xampp, windows-terminal

I know that in the new Windows Terminal I can add any custom profile, so I want to start XAMPP shell from there. In the settings json file I add the profile but I have a problem adding the right "commandline" variable value. I've tried "xampp_shell.bat" but it doesn't work. Can anyone please help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit the environment variable in your windows. Anything you want to run on the command line must have a path saved in the environment variable. Take a look here [how to access the command line for xampp on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753024/how-to-access-the-command-line-for-xampp-on-windows/46408671#46408671)

Answer (score 0):

Add a new profile in Windows Terminal. Duplicate the Command Prompt profile. Change the Command Line and Starting Directory in settings tab or open the JSON file. Starting Directory seems to be the key here so don't overlook it. You should get the # prompt same as using the XAMPP control panel Shell button.

"name": "XAMPP",
"commandline": "C:\xampp\xampp_shell.bat",
"startingDirectory": "C:\xampp"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).