# Should I install additional php when XAMPP has default php package in it?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm a begginer in Laravel and I installed XAMPP as local server. I noticed that my XAMPP already install php 7.4 as it's dependency. But when I tried php -v in www dir in php it shown.

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable
> program or batch file.

But in php directory is shown

> PHP 7.4.15 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2021 20:47:45) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017
> x64 )   Copyright (c) The PHP Group  Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c)
> Zend Technologies

So, should I install additional php in my system for development? Should the version of the php matche with XAMPP php 7.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php -v` will only tell you if you have PHP installed as a command line interface (PHP-CLI) which would enable you to run php code in cmd.exe or powershell. You'd normally not need this, but for reference here's how to enable it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753133 (mind the comment on Windows 10).

To check if PHP runs in your webserver environment (which is by default available in xampp), create a file `test.php` in your www folder with the following content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Call this file in a browser, you will get an overview of all php features available. Delete the file before you go productive, because it will also give hackers a lot of information (which you don't want).

Comment: So can I conclude that there is no need to download php again?

Comment: From what I see you should be good to go. Did you test with `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add XAMPP PHP to Environment Variables
[here is an instructions](https://dinocajic.medium.com/add-xampp-php-to-environment-variables-in-windows-10-af20a765b0ce) for Windows 10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).