# Error message when looking for directory in php when run in powershell

Tags: php, powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

First please excuse any grammar or spelling mistakes. English is my second language and it's 2AM at the time of writing this.
I was trying to create a php script that can be executed in powershell, which from inside a hyper-v virtual machine. This script would take files from a drive which is shared with the virtual machine and hashes these files.

I followed this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnBPBZv7qZo) for accessing the shared drive. This [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21958683) for executing php scripts in powershell. For that you need to set [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753133) environment variables.

The below code is what I am trying to execute and it is located at: `\\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php`

```
$directory = "\\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_data";
$directoryContents = scandir("$directory");
$counter = count($directoryContents, 0);
$hashes = [0, 0];
for($i = 2; $i < $counter; $i++)
{
$hash = hash_file("sha512", "$directory\$directoryContents[$i]");
array_push($hashes, $hash);
}
var_dump($hashes);
```

when I execute the code in powershell with the command: `php.exe \\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php`
I get the following error message:

```
PHP Warning: scandir(\tsclient\E\My_Projects
ew_data, \tsclient\E\My_Projects
ew_data): Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden. (code: 3) in \\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php on line 2

Warning: scandir(\tsclient\E\My_Projects
ew_data, \tsclient\E\My_Projects
ew_data): Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden. (code: 3) in \\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php on line 2
PHP Warning: scandir(\tsclient\E\My_Projects
ew_data): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in \\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php on line 2

Warning: scandir(\tsclient\E\My_Projects
ew_data): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in \\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php on line 2
PHP Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in \\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php on line 2

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in \\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php on line 2
PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in \\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php on line 3

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in \\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php on line 3
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(0)
}
```

> Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden

is german and roughly translates to:

> The system can not find the path specified

The two main things that I have noticed about the error messages are that:

1. when it returns the address path one of the backslashes is missing
2. it interperates the folder name as \new_code as \n and continues on the next line.

To fix this I have:

1. run other test files that just echo data and they work excelently.
2. tried reading the dir name from a .txt file. This returned an error message that it was unable to find the .txt file.
3. tried using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] this did not change a lot in the error message.

I have come to the conclusion that it almost seems that powershell/php thinks that \tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_code\hashing_script.php is a directory and is trying to search inside of it, which obviously won't work.

Thank you for taking your time to read this any and all suggestions/ideas/questions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be in the habit of protecting your backslashes.  Your string contains `\n`, which of course translates to a newline, not to the two characters you expect.  You either need to double the backslashes or use single quotes:

```
$directory = "\\\\tsclient\\E\\My_Projects\\new_data";
$directory = '\\tsclient\E\My_Projects\new_data';
```