# Creating a project with laraval - Composer and Php Issues

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

Been trying to use composer with no luck at all. I had added composer and PHP to my environmental variables with still no luck

Any time I try to run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

It comes back with is error

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
which: no php in (/c/Users/Myname/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Myname/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/xampp/php:/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/cmd:/c/Users/Myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts:/c/Users/Myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310:/c/Users/Myname/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/Myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/Myname/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/c/Users/Myname/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/Myname/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer: line 14: php: command not found
```

Comment: Do you have PHP installed properly? Try `php -v` then try `php.exe -v` then try  `C:\xampp\php\php -v` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753024/how-to-access-the-command-line-for-xampp-on-windows

Comment: The leading slash stuff in your path also looks suspicious to me. All the instances of `/c/` I believe should instead be c:\ or c:/ but I could be wrong. I haven't touched windows in a few years. You might also try using something like gitbash instead of command prompt if you're not already and see if there's any difference.